# Why does this codeigniter .htaccess file work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website which has a broken link structure. The initial page loads normally. My Navbar looks like:

```
<a class="brand" href="#">myproject</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/Facts">Facts</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/about">About</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact">Contact</a></li>
              <!--<li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/privacy">Privacy</a></li>-->
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I've tested it locally with the following .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This appears to fix the directory structure (I assumed) by turning:

```
http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact
```

into:

```
http://localhost/projectname/index.php/basecontroller/contact
```

as I look at it more closely I would have thought that it would create:

```
 http://localhost/index.php/projectname/basecontroller/contact
```

which should not work, but it is working! Can someone explain this?

Comment: `.htaccess` works from the current directory. If your project is located in `/projectname`, then the `.htaccess` rules will be applied assuming this folder as root. The rewrite seems perfectly logical to me. What confuses you?

Comment: "the .htaccess rules will be applied assuming this folder as root" .I think this is an important point and something I didn't realize. If you enter this as an answer I will accept it. -Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` works from the current directory. If your project is located in `/projectname`, then the `.htaccess` rules will be applied assuming this folder as root.

This means, the server is oblivious to the over all directory hierarchy of the server. If you place the `.htaccess` in `/dir1` it will *not* have the same effect as if it was placed in `/dir2`, but will instead just be applied to the respective directory.

If you want a `.htaccess` to work from the root of the server, you must place the file in the actual server root.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such thing as codeigniter htaccess. .htaccess is its own thing which is completely separate from codeigniter.  In order to get codeigniter to work without the index.php in the url use what wordpress uses for its htaccess file, its the same for codeigniter. here is a copy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

also make sure to remove index.php in application/config/config.php to look like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

let me know if this answered your question.

in your case , since your using localhost and the way you have it setup, change the rewrite rule to

RewriteRule . /projectname/index.php [L]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That is useful info.